# Element outside a browser window

Tags: javascript, object, window, position, element

In the past I saw a developer trying to debug a cool effect, which was an element displaying outside a browser window, quite like image 02 below.

**01. Normal:**

[image]

**02. Not normal but cool:**

[image]

Is it possible to do this with JavaScript?

Comment: Set it with css to be absolute, left -99999

Comment: I'd say not possible, but you could emulate the effect with a pop-up and parent window limitedly.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, This doesn't seem to work for me. I set it to positions relative, absolute and fixed as well, with a z-index of 1000000000. If it's possible with CSS that's amazing, but I get the feeling this can only be done with a programming language, such as JavaScript.

Comment: @Teemu, Do you mean using something like an alert?

Comment: JavaScript could not move stuff outside a window.

Comment: @JoshuaWaheed Rather a window opened with `window.open()`. You can show elements "outside" of a pop-up in the parent window. Actually in IEs (on a trusted page only) you can create totally chromeless child window with transparent background, and show an element there, but this is usually not for web environment though.

Comment: @Teemu, An example of `window.open()` shows that it does the same thing as html's `target="_blank"`.

Comment: @mplungjan, I see. Do you know anything that would allow me to accomplish this effect?

Comment: @JoshuaWaheed Actually it is not the same. You have more control over a window opend with JS.

Comment: Possibly FLEX which I have seen pull a window out of a window

Comment: @Teemu, Sorry, I'll look more into it and will let you know how it goes. I'm probably not understanding it fully.

Comment: @mplungjan, Thanks, I'll look into this and will get back to you.